# Can't locate a particular HTML element using findElements(), filter() or selectLink()

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, symfony-panther

[image: Screenshot of element]

I cannot figure out why the crawler is not able to find the element. It's a simple element...

I have tried running `$client->refreshCrawler()`

The website is very JS and AJAX heavy so I was wondering if maybe the content is somehow in a hidden DOM if that is at all possible?

I noticed when inspecting the a tag that there is an event and that has 'DOM2' next to it

These are all the attempts i've tested:

```
try {
            echo " 1 - Finding region competitions\n";
            echo $this->getCrawler()->filter('div[class="non-route race-button"]')->text();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "1 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 2 - Finding region competitions\n";
            echo $this->getCrawler()->filter('div [class="non-route race-button"]')->text();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "2 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 3 - Finding region competitions\n";
            echo $this->getCrawler()->filter('div[class=".non-route race-button"]')->text();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "3 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 4 - Finding region competitions\n";
            echo $this->getCrawler()->filter('div [class=".non-route race-button"]')->text();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "4 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 5 - Finding region competitions\n";
            $a = $this->getCrawler()->findElements(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::className('non-route race-button'));
            echo "NUM: ".count($a)."\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "5 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 6 - Finding region competitions\n";
            $b = $this->getCrawler()->findElements(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::className('.non-route race-button'));
            echo "NUM: ".count($b)."\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "6 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 7 - Finding region competitions\n";
            $c = $this->getCrawler()->findElements(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::tagName('data-test'));


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "7 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 8 - Finding region competitions\n";
            $d = $this->getCrawler()->findElements(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::linkText('All Races'));
            echo "NUM: ".count($d)."\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "8 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 9 - Finding region competitions\n";
            return $this->getCrawler()->selectLink('All Races')->link();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "9 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }

        try {
            echo " 10 - Finding region competitions\n";
            $this->getCrawler()->filterXPath('/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a')->click();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "10 bad\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
        }
```

But each one returns `The current node list is empty`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't waiting long enough for the DOM to update

I used `sleep(3);` before trying to access the element and it now works OK